# Compile and run Swift code inside an iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, llvm

Is it possible to compile/run Swift code, entered by a user, inside an iOS app? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is how to run or interpret Swift code that is provided at run time, like the Swift command-line REPL or the iPad's Swift Playgrounds app. The full answer is really much too complicated for stackoverflow.

You'll need to use the [Swift compiler source code](https://github.com/apple) to do this. Start by looking at [swift-lldb (the version of the llvm project's debugger with Swift support)](https://github.com/apple/swift-lldb), which does what you're describing.